# Functions on a Matrix in R

Tags: r, function, matrix, rows

Lets say I have a dataset with a column representing the years.

```
Years
2007
2008
2009
2011
2015
```

I want to subtract the row with the row below it and save the ans to a new column. such as for above data I want to make a function that subtracts 2008 to 2007, the ans is 1 and save this ans to a new column, the next would be 2009 - 2008, 2011 - 2009. the resulting matrix should look like

```
Year    Gap
2007    1
2008    1
2009    2
2011    4
2015    .
```

and so on
How can I make a function in R that will do this for me?

Comment: Look for `?diff`

Comment: @markus diff?? What do u mean

Comment: `diff` is the function you are looking for, i.e. `df$Gap <- c(diff(df$Years), NA)`

Comment: @markus got it. thank you :)